# Как исправить ошибку в получении последних координат методом getLastLocation

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

Хочу получить текущее местоположение, использую способ через google play service. Есть момент через получение последних координат. Но метод getLastLocation() возвращает null. Как это исправить? При этом полазив по форумам я понял что , в принципе, это не ошибка, просто нет последнего местоположения. Но тогда я получу текущее?

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверить, есть включены ли Wi/Fi/GPS. Если нет, метод вернет **null**.
2. Вызвать **mLocationClient.getLastLocation()** в методе **onConnected** или после того, как установлено соединение с Google Play Services.

Чтобы проверить, что location client подключен, вызвать метод:

```
mLocationClient.isConnected().
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем первую координату нужно получать через ReqestListner, а дальше как описано в документации google.